# Can you use a Wii U Virtual Console code for a 3DS Virtual Console game?

Tags: virtual-console

I'm planning to get the Super Mario Bros game, but its only for Wii U. I know it says for Wii U (And it may look stupid) But I've seen it on the eShop. So, Can I use the code?

Answer (score 2):

If the code is for the Wii U, then it will only work for the Wii U, regardless if the game is on both the 3DS eshop and the Wii U eshop. So no, it won't work for your 3DS if you have a WiiU code.